# Creating vector of vectors (2D array) inside a class - Error:C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, multidimensional-array, stdvector

So I have procedurally programmed a way to integrate equations using the Runge-Kutta 4(RK4) method in C++. I am currently trying to create an RK4 class to add more functionality to my program. However, when I set up my 2D arrays in the class, I receive the "C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations" error, that I didn't receive in the original program.

At first, I was using namespace std;, however I came across an answer that said that that was bad programming practice, so I erased that line and called std::vector instead. I also made sure to include the vector library, to no avail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>

class RK4 {
public:
    RK4(double x_i, double y_i, double z_i, double vx_i, double vy_i, double vz_i);
    //time-related stuff
    double dt = 0.01;
    int numtimes = 1000;

    int numvar = 3;
    double mu = 398589590898200.0;

    //setting up variables
    std::vector<vector<double> > position(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > velocity(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > rk1(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > rk2(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > rk3(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > rk4(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > vk1(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > vk2(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > vk3(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    std::vector<vector<double> > vk4(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
```

This is how I constructed the code in my original program, with no problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
// time related things
    //double t_i = 0; // initial time
    double dt = 0.01; // time step
    int numtimes = 10000; // how many steps taken

    vector<vector<double> > position(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > velocity(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));

    vector<vector<double> > rk1(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > rk2(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > rk3(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > rk4(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > vk1(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > vk2(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > vk3(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
    vector<vector<double> > vk4(numtimes,vector<double>(numvar));
}
```

I'm not quite sure why this call worked in my original(procedural) program, but not in my current program.

Comment: You cannot initialize `std::vector` as class members like that.  Use the member initialization list of your `RK4` constructor to initialize such members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move those `std::vector` initializations to the constructor of `RK4` and use the member initialization list syntax to initialize them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class RK4 
{
    double dt = 0.01;
    int numtimes = 1000;
    int numvar = 3;
    double mu = 398589590898200.0;

    //declaring vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > position;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > velocity;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk4;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk4;

   public:
    RK4(double x_i, double y_i, double z_i, double vx_i, double vy_i, double vz_i) : 
       position(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       velocity(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       rk1(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       rk2(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       rk3(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       rk4(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       vk1(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       vk2(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       vk3(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       vk4(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar))
    {}
};
```

---

Given the order of the member variables, you can also do this (but this requires that `position` be declared before any of the other vectors):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class RK4 
{
    double dt = 0.01;
    int numtimes = 1000;
    int numvar = 3;
    double mu = 398589590898200.0;

    //declaring vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > position;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > velocity;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk4;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk4;

   public:
    RK4(double x_i, double y_i, double z_i, double vx_i, double vy_i, double vz_i) : 
       position(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)),
       velocity(position),
       rk1(position),
       rk2(position),
       rk3(position),
       rk4(position),
       vk1(position),
       vk2(position),
       vk3(position),
       vk4(position)
    {}
};
```

The reason why this works is that `position` and all the other vectors are exactly the same size and start out with the same values.  So it becomes a little easier just to initialize the other vectors with `position`.  But again, this requires `position` to be declared in the class before the other vectors for this to work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I wanted to initialize the first rows of position and velocity would I also do that in the member initialization list? I've tried to initialize them inside with x_i, y_i, etc and get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

With classes, you can't initialize members outside of functions.  You can assign them in the constructor though.

Also, you wrote  "vector" in a bunch of places where you need "std::vector".  This should fix it:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class RK4 {
   public:
    RK4(double x_i, double y_i, double z_i, double vx_i, double vy_i, double vz_i) {
        double dt = 0.01;
        int numtimes = 1000;

        int numvar = 3;
        double mu = 398589590898200.0;

        //assigning the vectors
        position = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        velocity = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        rk1 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        rk2 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        rk3 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        rk4 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        vk1 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        vk2 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        vk3 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
        vk4 = std::vector<std::vector<double> >(numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar));
    }
    //time-related stuff
    double dt = 0.01;
    int numtimes = 1000;

    int numvar = 3;
    double mu = 398589590898200.0;

    //declaring vectors
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > position;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > velocity;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > rk4;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk1;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk2;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk3;
    std::vector<std::vector<double> > vk4;
};

int main() {
    RK4 r(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actually, your code is showing *assignment*, not initialization.  To initialize, you would use the member-initialization list.

Comment: True.  I fixed it.

Comment: No, it is still using assignment.  The constructor body should be empty.  Your solution only mimics what the OP was trying to do, and not explicitly do exactly what the OP intended (even though the results may turn out the same).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I fixed my description to match the code.  Now it's consistent.  The OP didn't specify whether they wanted initialization or assignment.

Answer (score 0):

In a function, you can use parenthesis to pass parameters to the constructor for a variable.  This does not work when specifying default values for member variables.  You have to use *uniform initialization*.

```
 std::vector<std::vector<double>> position{numtimes, std::vector<double>(numvar)};
```

This syntax - using curly braces - also works for when declaring variables, and you can use that same line in `main` to declare the `position` variable.

One other thing you get with uniform initialization is stronger type safety.  You can't specify a number that won't fit where you're trying to store it.  Where that is an issue in your code is that `numtimes` is an `int`, but the first parameter to the constructor for `vector` is a `size_t` - some form of `unsigned`.  So you'll need to change the declaration for `numtimes` to

```
unsigned numtimes = 10000;
```

Note also that you need to put `std::` in front of all the `vector` usages.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I fixed my code to match that syntax, however I am getting another error "function definition does not declare parameters". Does this mean that the line is not generating a 2D matrix of zeros? If so, is this characteristic of uniform initialization?